# SQLServerConnection Prelogin

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

Getting following error while using Hibernate with SQL serer 2000.

```
 Dec 12, 2015 12:54:20 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:7 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Error reading prelogin response: Connection reset
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:20 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:5 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Error reading prelogin response: Connection reset
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:20 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:6 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Error reading prelogin response: Connection reset
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:20 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:7 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Error reading prelogin response: Connection reset
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:20 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:5 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:20 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:6 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:20 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:7 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:20 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:7 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Error reading prelogin response: Connection reset
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:20 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:5 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Error reading prelogin response: Connection reset
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:20 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:7 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Error reading prelogin response: Connection reset
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:20 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:5 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:20 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:6 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Error reading prelogin response: Connection reset
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:20 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:6 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Error reading prelogin response: Connection reset
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:21 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:7 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:21 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:5 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Error reading prelogin response: Connection reset
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:21 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:6 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:21 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:7 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:21 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: ConnectionID:5 Prelogin error: host 192.168.107.100 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
    Dec 12, 2015 12:54:21 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
    WARNING: Conne
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems logging into MSSQL server from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335797/problems-logging-into-mssql-server-from-java)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335797/problems-logging-into-mssql-server-from-java